# How to add tooltip in map windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

My windows 8 phone app programatically add an image (as a pin) to a specific coordinataion in map using mapoverlay. And now i would like to add a tooltip to the image (pin) after tapping on it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
pinIMG = new Image();
                pinIMG.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/pin.png", UriKind.Relative));

MapOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                myLocationOverlay.Content = pinIMG;
                myLocationOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                myLocationOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(57.724611, 12.938945);

MapLayer myLocationLayer = new MapLayer();
myLocationLayer.Add(myLocationOverlay);
MyMap.Layers.Add(myLocationLayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an Image to the MapOverlay, consider adding an ExpanderView control that expands to add additional data. You'll need to download the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com) to get the [ExpanderView](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#1336207) control. While you're at it you might want to switch over to using [Map Extensions Pushpins](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#1336302) to get databinding support.

```cs
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MapLayer myLayer = new MapLayer();
    MapOverlay myOverlay = new MapOverlay()
                            {
                                GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(-17, 133)
                            };
    ExpanderView expander = new ExpanderView();

    expander.Header = new Image()
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative)),
        Width = 200
    };
    expander.ItemsSource = new[]
    {
        new TextBlock{ Text = "HELLO"}
    };
```

;

```
    myOverlay.Content = expander;
    myLayer.Add(myOverlay);
    myMap.Layers.Add(myLayer);
}
```

When we run this sample we can see the following icon over australia:

[image: Icon over australia]

And once we click ti we can see our "Hello" text show up:

[image: Text over australia]

A few ceavets: the code sample above is terrible. ExpanderView is meant to use both ItemSource and IteTemplate for multiple items databinding. Using it for a single item isn't great. The above code sample is also terrible since it creates UI elements in C# code whereas using Map Extensions could have placed this code in XAML.